# How to get these two controllers to function together for ionic app?

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-controller

Todo List: http://codepen.io/BltzLcht/pen/PzdLvz

Custom Timer: http://codepen.io/BltzLcht/pen/qNJmrX?editors=1000

I'm combining a timer with a Todolist. Both function individually but they don't work together. If I try to put a new ng-controller for the tasks, the timer will disappear.

Where and how can I change the controllers so they can do their own things? One thing that I'm wary about is the

```
 <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="newTask()">
    <i class="ion-compose icon"></i>
  </button>
```

I put it in the header bar for creating new tasks, but it seemed like the new ng-controller wouldn't span far enough to reach the ion-list, and that was important for the task apps

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $ionicListDelegate) {
$scope.tasks =
  [
    {title: "1.Make a second box in Create Task for a time variable ", completed: false},
    {title: "2.Make time variable display on right side", completed: false},
    {title: "3. Make a time variable button that leads to this timer", completed: false},
    {title: "4. Time variable transfers to next page http://codepen.io/comapedrosa/pen/ONYgzJ", completed: false}
  ];

$scope.newTask = function() {
  $ionicPopup.prompt({
    title: "New Task",
    template: "Enter task:",
    inputPlaceholder: "What do you need to do?",
    template1: "Enter time:",
    inputPlaceholder1: "How much time do you you require?",
    okText: 'Create task'

  }).then(function(res) {    // promise
    if (res) $scope.tasks.push({title: res, completed: false});
  })
};

$scope.edit = function(task) {
  $scope.data = { response: task.title };
  $ionicPopup.prompt({
    title: "Edit Task",
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(res) {    // promise
    if (res !== undefined) task.title = $scope.data.response;
    $ionicListDelegate.closeOptionButtons()

  })
};
```

})

Comment: Try using service if you want to function two controller together.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what that is

Comment: you can create a service and inject it in both controllers..Try to search if you have no idea..  you will find lots of example

Comment: I'm looking at it. Makes no sense how I can apply it :(

Answer (score 0):

The best way to communicate between the controllers is "Services" ...  ....